# Breaking change in Angular2 rc1?

Tags: angular, angular-cli

I'm upgrading an existing project to Angular2 rc1 and the beta1 version of the cli

A previously working piece of code:

```
<main [attr.style]="isEmbeded ? '' : 'margin-top: 82px;'" >
```

is no longer working it now renders as:

```
<main _ngcontent-mak-1="" style="unsafe">
```

Has something changed that I'm not aware of?

Comment: They yet need to fine-tune what values they allow by default. They added the sanitation functionality and it currently is a bit to eager about what it allows or removes.

Comment: Looks like it is the same problem you linked to. Never came across it during my searched

Answer (score 3):

Well I've not found an answer to why this is no longer allowed but I have managed to resolve it by using this instead:

```
<main [style.margin-top.px]="isEmbeded ? '' : '82'" >
```